# How to create a hotspot in Ubuntu to connect an Android phone?

Tags: networking, network-manager, android, 19.10

I am able to create a WiFi hotspot from the settings panel in Ubuntu 19.10. My Android phone is able to see that network, but on trying to connect to it with exact credentials, the phone is unable to connect. It shows **Connecting...** for a few seconds and then **Saves** that network instead of connecting to it. How can I solve this issue?

FYI: I am using Ubuntu 19.10, Android version 4.4.3 and my WiFi adapter's model is Realtek.

This is the output of `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 May 25 13:06 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

This is the output of `cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf`:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
```

Comment: Is `wpasupplicant` installed?

Comment: Yes, it is installed.

Comment: Is `dnsmasq-base` (or `dnsmasq`) installed?

Comment: Yes, `dnsmasq` is installed.

Comment: OK, edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Ubuntu's in-built hotspot program, I used [this](https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot). It worked like a charm!

Anybody having the problem like me, see [Connectify Hotspot alternatives for Linux](https://alternativeto.net/software/connectify/?platform=linux).